# how to pick a row for some fields conditionally with min max dates in the output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need a min(date1) max(date2) from a group(which is id) and other fields assosiated with max(date2)

below is how the source date looks like

id ------   date1 ------        date2 ------     other-data 
---------------------------------------------------------
1------02/12/2018------01/12/2018------abc
1------08/21/2018------06/12/2019------def
2------12/01/2018------03/03/2016------ghi
2------12/03/2018------06/30/2020------xyz
2------01/02/2018------05/10/2019------klm

I am not able to use group by as there are other fields that i dont want to group by on.

my expected output is

id---- min(date1) ----- max(date2) --other-data(associated with max(date2)
---------------------------------------------------
1   ------02/12/2018------06/12/2019------  def
2   ------01/02/2018 ------   06/30/2020-----xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use group by, you just need to use appropriate aggregate functions on your remaining other data and use the KEEP aggregate clause to indicate which record in the group to retain.  Heres a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecd9a/2) demonstrating it:

**Query 1**:

```
select id
     , min(date1)
     , max(date2)
     , max(other_data) keep (dense_rank last order by date2) od
  from table1
  group by id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecd9a/2/0)**:

```
| ID |            MIN(DATE1) |            MAX(DATE2) |  OD |
|----|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----|
|  1 | 2018-02-12 00:00:00.0 | 2019-06-12 00:00:00.0 | def |
|  2 | 2018-01-02 00:00:00.0 | 2020-06-30 00:00:00.0 | xyz |
```